# Media Players breaking the videos

Tags: ati, vlc

I have a problem with my Media Players in Ubuntu 12.04 . When I play a video in VLC and SM Player, the video is breaking, that means video pause and skip but sound is well. I have installed ATI/AMD Proprietary FGLRX graphics driver.

Comment: Often, high-resolution videos(especially in H.264) have severe stuttering and video arfitfacts on older machines, while sound is unaffected. What type of CPU do you have?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ intel CORE i5

Comment: The usage of 'breaking' irritates me. Is the video playback bad or are the videos in fact harmed during playback?

Comment: video is paused and skip in fact harmed

Comment: Can you please define "breaking"!?

Comment: sound and video do not match.sound is good but video is like slow motion and it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

maybe installing codecs trough follow this guide can fix it http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-mplayer-and-multimedia-codecs-libdvdcss2w32codecsw64codecs-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise.html#more-13171

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.